# I want to use awk to print rearranged fields then print from the 4th field to the end

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file containing filesize, filedate, filetime, and filepath records. The filepath can contain spaces and can be very long (classical music names). I would like to print the file with filedate, filetime, filesize, and filepath. The first part, without the filepath is easy:

```
awk '{print $2,$3,$1}' filelist.txt
```

This works, but it prints the record on two lines:

```
awk '{print $2,$3,$1,$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' filelist.txt
```

I've tried using cut -d' ' -f '2 3 1 4-' , but that doesn't allow rearranging fields. I can fix the two line issue using sed to join. There must be a way to only use awk. In summary, I want to print the 2nd, 3rd, 1st, and from the 4th field to the end. Can anyone help?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: What goes wrong when you just try to add `$4` at the end? `awk '{print $2, $3, $1, $4}' filelist.txt`

Comment: @leekaiinthesky As OP said, the filepath may contain spaces, as such it won't fit in `$4`; instead it can spread into unpredictable number of fields `$4`, `$5`, `$6` and so on. Consider a file path `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\something` – it will split into six fields!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [`print` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Print) in `awk` always prints a newline in the end (technically `ORS`, which defaults to a newline), your first `print` will break the output in two lines.

With [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printf), on the other hand, you completely control the output with your format string. So, you can print the first three fields with `printf` (without the newline), then set them to `""`, and just finish off with the `print $0` (which is equivalent to `print` without arguments):

```
awk '{ printf("%s %s %s",$2,$3,$1); $1=$2=$3=""; print }' file
```

Comment: Is the `$0` necessary to `print` if it is the only parameter? AFAIR `print` prints $0 by default, so the `print` instruction alone should suffice.

Comment: You're right, I've added that to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid awk when I can. If I understand correctly what you have said -

```
while read size date time path
do echo "$date $time $size $path"
done < filelist.txt
```

You could `printf` instead of `echo` for more formatting options.
Embedded spaces in $path won't matter since it's the last field.

Answer (score 0):

I have no `awk` at hand to test but I suppose you may use `printf` to format a one-line output. Just locate the third space in `$0` and take a substring from that position through the end of the input line.

You may also try to swap fields *before* a standard `print`, although I'm not sure it will produce desired results...

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to delimit your fields with something like `<tab>`, so subsequent operations are easier... (I can see you used `cut` without `-d`, so maybe your data is already tab delimited.)

```
echo 1 2 3 very long name | 
  sed -e 's/ /\t/' -e 's/ /\t/' -e 's/ /\t/' | 
  awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2, $3, $1, $4}'
```

The first line generates data. The `sed` command substitutes first three spaces in each row with `\t`. Then the `awk` works flawlessly, outputting tab delimited data again (you need a reasonably new `awk`).

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ echo '1 2 3 4 5 6' | awk '{print $3, $2, $1, gensub(/([^ ]+){3}/,"",1)}'
3 2 1 4 5 6
```

With any awk:

```
$ echo '1 2 3 4 5 6' | awk '{rest=$0; sub(/([^ ]+ ){3}/,"",rest); print $3, $2, $1, rest}'
3 2 1 4 5 6
```